# Internet Explorer tries to download Google links as a file

Tags: internet-explorer

Having a really peculiar problem one a couple of our client machines.

Randomly, on some Google links, IE tries to download the link as a file:

[image: problem]

I *think*, though I can't say for definite, that these links may exclusively be to YouTube.

Here's the client machine's IE details:

[image: IE details]

I don't even know how to go about diagnosing this problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need to know if they are exclusive to Youtube or not.  The next step is **Reset** IE9.  `Internet Options -> Advanced`.  Is upgrading to IE11 an option?

Comment: It isn't at the moment, unfortunately. I'll go and get that extra information now.

Comment: @Ramhound, it was just YouTube links... and your Reset advice worked. Stupid of me not to check that first. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it Correct. Thank you :)